# Passing properties from parent controller to child controller in Kohana 3

Tags: php, model-view-controller, kohana, kohana-3

I am using Kohana 3 and using a middle controller named controller_Facebook that is extended from Controller_Template and then extending Controller_Home from Controller_Facebook. I am setting two properties in Controller_Facebook and trying to use them in Controller_Home but it not available there. It gives null value. My code is similar to following:

```
class Controller_Facebook extends Controller_Template{

        public $template='template';
        public $facebook;
        public $session;

    public function __contstruct(){
        include_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/facebook_class.php");
            global $facebook;
            $facebook = new Facebook(array(
              'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
              'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
              'cookie' => true,
            ));
            $this->facebook=$facebook;
            $this->session = $facebook->getSession();
    }
}
```

Then in Home_Controller :

```
  class Controller_Home extends Controller_Facebook{


        public function  __contstruct() {
                parent::__contstruct();

        }



        public function action_index()
    {
                global $facebook;
        $this->template->content=new View('home');
        $this->template->selected='home';   var_dump($this->facebook);
                $this->template->app_id='123';

                var_dump($facebook);

                $this->template->session=$this->session;

    }

}
```

Also if I echo some thing in parent class then it doesnot output that. It working in facebook also so does that mean that my parent constructor is working? I think it is working. Please tell me if some one think that I am doing some thing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do **not** overload `__construct` blindly, it will break your controllers. You should be doing this in the `before()` method. Be sure to call `parent::before()` after you are done.

And that `global` stuff is totally unnecessary. Just set `$this->facebook` and then access it later with `$this->facebook`.

Comment: what I need to do in before? you mean I need to define a before method and do parent::before in that? or I need to do the do the things in before what I am doing in constructor of controller_facebook? Can you please clarify

Comment: oh thanks, that works, thanks a lot and also thanks to stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 1):

You've spelt __construct wrong.

Also you don't need to access the global if you've set it as a class property.

Just access it with

```
$this->facebook
```

Comment: oh yes, what the bad mistake I did

Comment: by correcting this it is saying now this error:
ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Call to a member function body() on a non-object
it shows error here:
 public function after()
41  {
42   if ($this->auto_render === TRUE)
43   {
44    $this->response->body($this->template->render());
45   }
46
in SYSPATH/classes/kohana/controller/template.php [ 44 ]
47   return parent::after();
48  }

Comment: Its because of your constructor. Move it code to a public function before() and dont forget to add parent::before() call.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, it will be better to create Kohana wrapper for FB class, and then use it in your controllers. Like this:

```
$this->facebook = Facebook::instance(); // wrapper will automatically load config with appId etc
$this->session = $this->facebook->get_session();
```

PS. May be Kohana already has this implementation? Something like https://github.com/zombor/Kohana-Facebook.